# Can't resize layered iframes via mouse using jquery-ui.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, iframe

I have been trying to upscale the code example resizing 1 iframe but doing it for a layered set of iframes.  Basically I have 3 rows of div table/table-cells where the 2nd and 3rd rows have two or more cells with 2 iframes in each of them (title and content).  See html code and stylesheet below.

The problem is I am trying to resize the row but the iframes are then bigger then the div table and div cell blocks.  I am not sure why this is happening.  I have not been able to find any examples of more then one iframe in one div to look at.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!--
Page:   Generate the Pass Coverage Tool Layout

Description:
        This page is going to dynamically create the Pass Plan web page.  The user is selecting 
        what panels they want to see on the page (timeline, missions contacts, and Non - Contact Times GMT.

        The missions that are displayed on the missions panel are also selected by the user so there can be one or
        more missions selected.

        Finally the contact filter is passed down to the Missions columns in the mission panel.

        Inputs:
    panels - What panels are to be displayed, i.e. timeline, mission contact ranges, and/or Non - Contact Times GMT.
       tl- Timeline
           ct- Contact Times<br
           nct - Non - Contact Times GMT
    mission - List of missions to display.
       Aura, Aqua, Terra, etc.
    Filter - List of TRDS and ground stations to filter out.
       SGS, AGS, SKS, TDS, 275, etc.

Author:   John kerich

Revision: 12/22/2015

-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Pass Coverage Tool V2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/poller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pp_style_v2.css">
  </head>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('#resizable1').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#resizable2').resizable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','none');
         },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('iframe').css('pointer-events','auto');
      }
  });
  });
  </script>

<body>
  <iframe id="TLB" src="pp_TimeLine.php" scrolling="auto" width="100%" style="border:none"></iframe>

  <div id="resizable1" class="Row">
    <div class="Column">
      <iframe id="TerraMT" src="pp_TerraTitle.html" scrolling="no"></iframe><br>
      <iframe id="TerraMB" src="pp_ContactRangesPanel.php?sc=terra&path=/var/www/html/java_clocks/terra/terra_aos_times&filter=N;#target" 
           data-path=/java_clocks/terra/terra_aos_times scrolling="auto"></iframe><br>
    </div>

    <div class="Column">
      <iframe id="AuraMT" src="pp_AuraTitle.html" scrolling="no"></iframe><br>
      <iframe id="AuraMB" src="pp_ContactRangesPanel.php?sc=aura&path=/var/www/html/java_clocks/aura/aura_aos_times&filter=N;#target" 
           data-path=/java_clocks/aura/aura_aos_times scrolling="auto"></iframe><br>
    </div>

    <div class="Column">
      <iframe id="AquaMT" src="pp_AquaTitle.html" scrolling="no"></iframe><br>
      <iframe id="AquaMB" src="pp_ContactRangesPanel.php?sc=aqua&path=/var/www/html/java_clocks/aqua/aqua_aos_times&filter=N;#target" 
           data-path=/java_clocks/aqua/aqua_aos_times scrolling="auto"></iframe><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="resizable2">
    <div class="Column2">
      <iframe id="BT" src="pp_BreakTitle.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      <iframe id="BB" src="pp_BreakTimePanel.php?type=breaktimes_non" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="Column2">
      <iframe id="BNT" src="pp_BreakNonTitle.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      <iframe id="BNB" src="pp_BreakTimePanel.php?type=breaktimes" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

pp_style_v2.css

```
.Row
{
    display: table;     /* Let the element behave like a <table> element */
    width: 100%;        /* expand as far was you then table */
    table-layout: fixed;    /* The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells */
    border-spacing: 5px;    /* padding around the table */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.Column
{
    display: table-cell;    /* this is a table-cell */
    table-layout: auto; /* let the browser do it */
    width: 100%;        /* expand the cell to maximum size */
}
#TerraMT {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}
#TerraMB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}
#AuraMT {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}
#AuraMB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}
#AquaMT {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}
#AquaMB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;    
  z-index: 1;
}

#resizable2
{
    display: table;     /* Let the element behave like a <table> element */
    width: 100%;        /* expand as far was you then table */
    table-layout: fixed;    /* The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells */
    border-spacing: 5px;    /* padding around the table */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.Column2
{
    display: table-cell;    /* this is a table-cell */
    table-layout: auto; /* let the browser do it */
    width: 100%;        /* expand the cell to maximum size */
}

#BT {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
#BB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
#BNT {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
#BNB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
span.CRMissionTitle
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #999999;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center
}

span.ENCTTitle
{
    font-family:arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight=bold;
    text-align:center
}

span.ENCTGTitle
{
    font-family:arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight=bold;
    text-align:center
}

span.today
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.tomorrow
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #808080;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.clocklabel
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #33ffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span.illegal
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;

    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.generic
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none:
}
```

After stretching the second row down the iframe is now longer then the div block.  So what am I doing wrong?

[Picture of page after resizing bottom row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXQte.png)

Comment: Why do you have two DOCTYPEs? Also, the particular doctype you have there triggers Quirks mode, which is not recommended; different browsers have different quirks.

Comment: Because its a copy past error in the script, I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..  did you try setting your Iframe to `position: relative` so that they always stay withing the parent dimensions?

Comment: Should have used this to respond, see comment on position:relative above.

Answer (score 0):

I added "position: relative" first to the iframes tags in the style sheet, then to the div Column2, and finally to the resizable2 with no change.  I also tried just adding it to the div tags to be sure.  The iframe BNB and BB are still resizing more then the div blocks are.